# Google map get the total address from longitude and latitude values

Tags: php, google-maps, jquery

I am going through [gmap3 plugin](http://gmap3.net/en/) for google map. Here I have got the `longitude value and latitude value` from the google map code. Now I want the address of this values like `country name state name and city name etc`. So how to get al these values from `longitude and latitude` values. My code looks like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#map').blur(function() {
    //console.log('hello');
    var the_address = jQuery(this).val();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latLng = geocoder.geocode({
      address: the_address
    }, function(results, status) {

  /// IF WE HAVE A RESULT
  if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
    lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
    jQuery('#latitude').val(lat);
    jQuery('#longitude').val(lng);

    jQuery(gMap).gmap3({
      get: {
        name: 'marker',
        all: true,
        callback: function(objs) {
          jQuery.each(objs, function(i, obj) {
            obj.setMap(null);
          })
        }
      },
      map: {
        options: {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
        }
      },
        marker: {
          values: [{ latLng:[lat, lng] }],
          //jQuery(console.log(values));
          options: {
            draggable: true,
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
             "http://gmap3.net/skin/gmap/magicshow.png",
             new google.maps.Size(32, 37, "px", "px")
           ),
          },
          events: {
            mouseup: function(marker, event, context) {
              //// GETS MARKER LATITUDE AND LONGITUDE
              var thePos = marker.getPosition();
              var theLat = thePos.jb;
              var theLng = thePos.kb;
              jQuery('#latitude').val(theLat);
              jQuery('#longitude').val(theLng);
           },
           dragend: function(marker, event, context) {
            jQuery(this).gmap3({
              getaddress:{
                latLng:marker.getPosition(),
                callback:function(results){
                  var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
                  infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:"infowindow"}),
                  content = results && results[1] ? results && results[1].formatted_address : "no address";
                  if (infowindow){
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                  } else {
                  jQuery(this).gmap3({
                  infowindow:{
                    anchor:marker, 
                    options:{content: content}
                  }
                });
              }
            }
          }
        });
           },

         }
       }
     });
      } else {
        alert('Could not find the latitude and longitude for the address '+the_address);
              }
      });
    });
});
```

Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to get that? You can just reverse geocode with Lat and Lng to get the full address.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you want to have that full address but it is easy to get it. If you want it from the result of your `Geocoder` you can get the full address just by calling `results[0].formatted_address`.

If you want to get the address just by filling in the lat and long values you can do a Reverse Geocode:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon) }, function(results, status){
    console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
});
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=nl#ReverseGeocoding